# Retrieving the image output from another program/process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding a program  A that needs the image output from another program B, i tried with libraries for taking screenshots but then i should have the program B on top so it doesn't work for me, another thing to consider is the refresh rate i could get with it, i need a refresh rate at least of 30fps/sec.

I searched and the only thing i found is accesing the ram to cheat the program B, you guys know any package/library that can help me to get the job done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save the image to file with one program and read it with the other

Comment: I can't modify the code of program B, it's an external program to me

Comment: Does program B output only to screen? Is there a save button anywhere in program B? If so, using autohotkey to hit the save button would probably work

Comment: No, think about program B as a video player, it can't do anything else that just changing his image

Comment: If you have no other interface to program B, then screenshots or hacking the video buffer are the only ways to do it. I still recommend using autohotkey though

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will consider about it